# jquery -- one datepicker and one timepicker cannot work on one page

Tags: jquery, datepicker, timepicker

I have two input box on one page, one uses datepicker and another uses timepicker.

If I input an invalid time in time input box, it will reset date input box.

Anyone can help me fix this bug?

Thanks

```
<input Value="2012-11-20" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{4}(\-)\d{2}(\-)\d{2}$" id="HappenDate" name="HappenDate" type="text" value="" />

<input Value="08:14:02.600" data-val="true" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{2}(:)\d{2}(:)\d{2}(.)\d{1,3}$" id="HappenTime" name="HappenTime" type="text" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#HappenDate").datepicker();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#HappenTime").timepicker({
        showSecond: true,
        showMillisec: true,
        stepMillisec: 100,
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss.l'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: First of all you don't need two $(document).ready(function(){}) declarations, you can do it all in the one.

Comment: Also I am assuming you are using some sort of validation plugin? Or how are you determining whether or not a time is valid?

Comment: what timepicker plugin are you using? there isn't one in jqueryui by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only one $(document).ready(function ()